# C - Using strtok gives me only the first word of each line?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, strtok

My code is as follows. I am using a struct and taking in an input text file. I separate it into lines, then attempt to separate each line into its individual words. Using strtok, it is currently only printing the first word of each line. How can I fix this?

```
typedef struct {
    char linewords[101];
    char separateword[101];
} line;
```

The following is in main:

```
line linenum[101];
char var[101]
char *strtok(char *str, const char delim);

while fgets(linenum[i].linewords, 101, stdin) != NULL) {

    char* strcopy();
    char* strtok();
    strcpy(linenum[i].separateword,linenum[i].linewords);

    strtok(linenum[i].separateword, " "); /*line i'm referring to*/
    i++;
    }
}
```

I apologise in advance for any confusion. What I want is to have it so linenum[i].separateword[0] will return the first word, etc. Is this possible? Or is there another way of splitting my input into words?

Thank you

Comment: The second call must use `NULL`.

Comment: @Pavel Does this mean that after the current strtok line I should add 'strtok(NULL, " "); ?

Comment: To get all the words in a string, you need to call `strtok()` repeatedly. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm for an example.

Comment: @KittiCat: Yes, see the link posted by NPE or the documentation for strtok in your system. When it works for you, please consider submitting an answer with the fixed code if there's not one already.

Comment: @NPE Thanks for that! Really awesome. Just out of curiosity, this is printing the whole line as one word: can I split it up so that each word is stored in a different part of linenum[i].separateword[j]? That is, the first word of the first line could be like linenum[1].separateword[0]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char linewords[101];
    char *separateword[51];
} line;

int main(void){
    line linenum[101];
    int i = 0;

    while(fgets(linenum[i].linewords, sizeof(linenum[i].linewords), stdin) != NULL) {
        char *token, *delm = " \t\n";
        int j = 0;
        for(token = strtok(linenum[i].linewords, delm);
            token;
            token = strtok(NULL, delm)){
            linenum[i].separateword[j++] = token;
        }
        linenum[i++].separateword[j] = NULL;
    }
    {//test print
        char **p = linenum[0].separateword;
        while(*p)
            puts(*p++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry to be a massive pain, but could you please tell me how this works? I've had a few reads through and I'm a bit confused!

Comment: @KittiCat this save pointer cut  by strtok the position of the word in the line.

Comment: @KittiCat: Perhaps you need to activate C99 mode in your compiler... e.g. `gcc -std=c99`.

Comment: Enclosed in `{ }` a test print part if necessary.